# Memory usage of processes

Tags: linux, text, process, heap-memory, stack-memory

Asked this question in my Operating Systems class and after hours of searching, I cannot seem to come up with the proper answer:

"Assume you have three processes running on a computer.  How many text, heap, and stack segments are there and what do they contain"

We are doing most of our work in a 64-bit Linux environment.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking if there are multiple threads of execution within each process, how many segments?

Comment: I posted the exact question given on the homework assignment within the quotes.  I'm not sure if the question is asking for the exact size of each or just how many exist, which for instance would be 3 stacks for 3 processes.

Comment: I think the question is just asking what would be contained within the text segment, stack segment, and heap segment.  I don't think it's asking for the memory layout or the offsets linux uses.